# Proper Akka IO(Http) unbinding

Tags: akka, spray

Issuing `IO(Http) ! Http.Bind` starts listening on a port and accepting connections. However, `Http.Unbind` message doesn't do the opposite - the port remains open. That is, it gets processed and the log shows:

```
DEBUG | TcpListener  | Unbinding endpoint /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:38080
DEBUG | TcpListener  | Unbound endpoint /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:38080, stopping listener
INFO  | HttpListener | Unbound from /0.0.0.0:38080
```

But the port is still taken by the application.

TcpListener's source code shows that `Bind` registers the socket channel in the selector, but unbinding just closes the channel. For the selector to let that socket actually go, one must make a `Selector.select*()` call and that (I assume) doesn't happen.

Somehow I don't think it's an Akka bug, but rather, I'm doing something wrong. What is the proper way of unbinding an `IO(Http)` socket then?

Answer (score 0):

Unbind and wait for the Unbound response is the correct way. But usually operating systems do not immediately show the recently freed ports as free, but rather retain them for a little longer in case the app wants to re-use it. For example, in Java, if you bind a socket you need to specify

```
serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
```

explicitly to have it available as soon as unbound.

My guess is either you are not waiting for the Unbound message in your code correctly (though it seems not the case from your logs), or you are experiencing just this scenario.

Comment: I do receive the `Unbound` command. It's not a temporary state either - the socket stays in `LISTENING` state for hours, until I shut down the whole application.

Comment: Would it be possible that you are unbinding tcp but not udp or viceversa?

Comment: Nope, I'm pretty sure spray-can doesn't use HTTP over UDP.